MariaDB cluster with Galera-Abitrator-4 [gcs_proto_ver: 3]
M1,M2,M3 are 3 machines running Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
recently (june2024) .
After apt update & upgrade
M1 & M2 are MariaDB nodes Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.18-MariaDB
and. M3 is arbitrator using galera-arbitrator-4 Ver 4.11.r
The problem is M3 because  garbd joins the cluster (/var/log/syslog),  but after 2s fails with
FATAL: ./gcs/src/gcs_group.cpp:group_check_proto_ver():329: Group requested gcs_proto_ver: 3, max supported by this node: 2.Upgrade the node before joining this group.Need to abort.
I didn't found any config for garbd to set gcs_proto_ver in /etc/defaults/garbd
or a source for galera-arbitrator to change code and recompile
Hopefully there is someone there with an elegant solution to avoid installing MariaDB as 3rd node on M3.
Thanks

got it !!!
for gcs_proto_ver:3 the garbd >= 4.18 version is needed so:
apt remove galera-4 galera-arbitrator-4  #cleaning

since Debian repositorie is not updated must use galeracluster sourcess
cd /tmp
# --- get packages ---
wget https://releases.galeracluster.com/galera-4/debian/pool/main/g/galera-4/galera-4_26.4.18%2B1bullseye_amd64.deb
wget https://releases.galeracluster.com/galera-4/debian/pool/main/g/galera-4/galera-arbitrator-4_26.4.18%2B1bullseye_amd64.deb
# --- install ----
apt install ./galera-4_26.4.18+1bullseye_amd64.deb
apt install ./galera-arbitrator-4_26.4.18+1bullseye_amd64.deb
# --- if any warning reports about dependencies ---
apt install --fix-broken

assuming the sevice is still enabled (else systemctl enable garbd) and cluster config exists (else nano /etc/default/garb) just:
systemctl start garbd # --- iupi --- # 


using the default repo's from ubuntu, you will install an old version of arbitrator.
Update your sources regarding to this site:
https://mariadb.org/download/?t=repo-config&d=22.04+%22jammy%22&v=11.4&r_m=mva
After that, run
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade

it will fetch the newest packages.
If you did not have arbitrator installed yet, install it:
apt-get install galera-4 galera-arbitrator-4

:)

thanks for the answer -- your approach is a bit risky but leads me to find last version of galera  not updated on debian repository but on developer
